# Linq nesting relationships and DTOs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm getting data from an Oracle database and creating an API for internal use. Some of the classes are (shortened for brevity):

CustomerOrderTab

```
    Public partial class CustomerOrderTab
    Public string OrderNo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerMV")]
    public string CustomerNo { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerOrderLineTab> CustomerOrderLines { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerOrderChargeTab> CustomerOrderCharge { get; set; }
    public List<ShipmentOrderLineTab> ShipmentOrderLines { get; set; }
    public CustomerMV CustomerMV { get; set; }
```

CustomerOrderDTO

```
    Public class OrderDTO
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLinesDTO> OrderLines { get; set; }
    public List<OrderChargesDTO> OrderCharges { get; set; }
    public List<ShipmentOrderLinesDTO> ShipmentOrderLines { get; set; }
```

ShipmentOrderLineTab

```
    public partial class ShipmentOrderLineTab
    public decimal ShipmentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerOrderTab")]
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }
    public ShipmentTab Shipment { get; set; }
```

ShipmentOrderLineDTO

```
    public class ShipmentOrderLinesDTO
    public decimal ShipmentId { get; set; }
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }
    public ShipmentTab MyShipment { get; set; }
```

ShipmentTab

```
    public partial class ShipmentTab
    [ForeignKey("ShipmentOrderLineTab")]
    public decimal ShipmentId { get; set; }
    public string ShipperAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string ShipperAddress2 { get; set; }
    public List<ShipmentHandlingUnitTab> ShipmentHandlingUnits { get; set; }
```

ShipmentDTO

```
    public class ShipmentDTO
    public decimal ShipmentId { get; set; }
    public string ShipViaCode { get; set; }
    public string ShipmentPayer { get; set; }
    public List<ShipmentHandlingUnitDTO> ShipmentHandlingUnitDTOs { get; set; }
```

This Works:

```
    var orderLines = from o in _context.CustomerOrderTab
                         .Where(o => o.OrderNo == orderno)
                         select new OrderDTO()
                         {
                             OrderNo = o.OrderNo,
                             CustomerName = o.CustomerMV.CustomerName,

    This is a child of the order     ShipmentOrderLines = o.ShipmentOrderLines
    This works          .Select(ob => new ShipmentOrderLinesDTO
                             {
                                 ShipmentId = ob.ShipmentId,
                                 OrderNo = ob.OrderNo,
                                 MyShipment = ob.Shipment
    Adding this does not work         .Select(y => new ShipmentDTO
    The error says that ShipmentTab
     Doesn’t have a definition for Select    {
                                        }
                             }).ToList()
```

Shipment is a child of ShipmentOrderLine (there will only be one shipment per line)

ShipmentOrderLine is a child of CustomerOrder (there can be many lines per order)

I think the problem is that there is only one shipment per line but I've tried lots of things and can't get it to map to my DTO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your model:

ShipmentOrderLineDTO

```
public class ShipmentOrderLinesDTO
public decimal ShipmentId { get; set; }
public string OrderNo { get; set; }
public ShipmentDTO MyShipment { get; set; }
```

Select is only used to project a collection.  For non-collections, you just create a new object...

```
var orderLines = _context.CustomerOrderTab
  .Where(o => o.OrderNo == orderno)
  .Select(o => new OrderDTO {
    OrderNo = o.OrderNo,
    CustomerName = o.CustomerMV.CustomerName,
    ShipmentOrderLines = o.ShipmentOrderLines
      .Select(ob => new ShipmentOrderLinesDTO {
        ShipmentId = ob.ShipmentId,
        OrderNo = ob.OrderNo,
        MyShipment = new ShipmentDTO {
          ShipmentId = ob.Shipment.ShipmentId,
          ...
          ShipmentHandlingUnits = ob.Shipment.ShipmentHandlingUnits
            .Select(shu=> new ShipmentHandlingUnitDTO {
              ...
            }).ToList()
        }
      }
    }).ToList()
```

Now with that all said, I typically have mapping extension methods on my data model classes, which allow things like this:

```
var orderLines = _context.CustomerOrderTab
  .Where(o=>o.OrderNo == orderno)
  .Select(o=> o.ToDto());
```

Example class:

```
public static class CustomerOrderTabExtensions {
  public static CustomerOrderDto ToDto(this CustomerOrderTab cot) {
    return new CustomerOrderDto {
      OrderNo = cot.OrderNo,
      ...
      OrderLines = cot.CustomerOrderLines
        .Select(col=>col.ToDto())
        .ToList()
    }
  }
}
```

Or use [Automapper](https://automapper.org/).